# Markowitz mean variance optimization in python using scipy optimize

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to find the efficient frontier for a portfolio of 10 stocks. I first load the data (data) which includes the weekly returns for 10 stocks over 104 periods. Then i randomize weights to plot arbitrary portfolios using this code:

```
def random_weights(n):
    a = np.random.rand(n)
    return a/a.sum()

def initial_portfolio(data):
    cov = data.cov()
    expected_return = np.matrix(data.mean())
    weights = np.matrix(random_weights(expected_return.shape[1]))

    mu = weights.dot(expected_return.T)
    sigma = np.sqrt(weights.dot(cov.dot(weights.T)))
    var = weights.dot(cov.dot(weights.T))

    return mu[0,0], sigma[0,0], var[0,0]#, cov, expected_return, weights


def initial_portfolio_other(data):
    cov = np.cov(data)
    expected_return = np.matrix(data.mean())
    weights = np.matrix(random_weights(expected_return.shape[1]))

    mu = weights.dot(expected_return.T)
    sigma = np.sqrt(weights * cov.dot(weights.T))
    var = weights * cov.dot(weights.T)

    return cov, expected_return, weights

n_portfolios = 1000

means, stds, var = np.column_stack([
        initial_portfolio(data)
        for _ in range(n_portfolios)
])



plt.xlabel('Standard deviation')
plt.ylabel('Expected return')
plt.scatter(stds, means)
plt.axis([0.02, 0.035, 0.002,0.009])
plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
plt.show()
```

So far the code works fine, next i want to find the efficient frontier by minimizing the portfolio variance for 1000 weekly returns. This is the code i have so far

```
def calc_var(w, c):
    return np.dot(np.dot(w, c),w)


def optimal_portfolio(returns):

    n = len(returns.mean())
    returns = np.matrix(returns)
    avg_returns = np.matrix(returns.mean())
    #min_mu = min(returns.mean())
    #max_mu = max(returns.mean())
    mus = np.random.uniform(0.001,0.03,1000)

    S = np.cov(returns, rowvar = False)
    pbar = np.matrix(returns.mean())

    var = lambda w: w.dot(S.dot(w.T))

    frontier_mean, frontier_var, frontier_weights = [], [], [] 

    for r in mus:
        w = np.ones([n]) / n
        w_bound = [(0, 1) for i in range(n)]
        w_constraint = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda w: sum(w) - 1.})

        optimal_w = scipy.optimize.minimize(var, w, method = 'SLSQP', constraints = w_constraint, bounds = w_bound)
        frontier_mean.append(r)
        frontier_var.append(calc_var(w, S))
        frontier_weights.append(optimal_w.x)

    return frontier_mean, frontier_var, frontier_weights

result = optimal_portfolio(data)
```

The output is a list of 1000 variances which are all identical and ofcourse 1000 set of weights which are all identical. I know something is missing, but i just can't figure out what it is. I keep seeing the args argument in the minimize function being used by other people but i honestly have no clue how or what to pass through it. If anyone has any experience in optimization in python especially in mean variance optimization i would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Looks like `frontier_var.append(calc_var(w, S))` is always conducting the same calculation.  `w` is an array of ones, and `S` is the covariance matrix of `returns`.  As it's not dependent on `mus`, you'll get the same outcome for every iteration in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are too few constraints. The optimization should also include the constraint that equalizes portfolio return to r; something like this:

```
w_constraint2 = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda w: np.dot(avg_returns,np.matrix(w).T) - r})
```

But, for this, you would have to write the statement `avg_returns = np.matrix(returns.mean())` before you convert returns to a numpy matrix. Otherwise, `average_returns is a 1 x 1 matrix (instead of 1 x num_stocks)`

Comment: And also, you should append optimal_w.x to frontier_std. You are just appending the initial weights (w) in every loop.